# Make only part of a div visible

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, visibility, mousemove

I want a `div` that only partly has its content visible. I want the user to use his mouse horizontally (i.e., left-to-right mouse movement) to change which part of the `div` is visible.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have to provide some more information, your question is quite vague. If you only want to have a part visible, then subdivide the div into parts.

Comment: have a look at the [overflow property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html)

Comment: do you want the user to open/close the visible area with a dragging style?

Comment: Ok, I will try to be more specific: The visible area of the div is changed somewhat like if there where a horizontal scrollbar, but without the scrollbar: If the mouse pointer is inside the div, then the center of the visible area is where the pointer is. The visible area has full hight and x pixels width. I tried the overflow part, but the text I had in the div then got adjusted into the visible div horizontally speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The HTML and CSS**

If I understand your question correctly, you have a `div` that is *x* pixels wide, and its contents are *y* pixels wide where *x* > *y*. In other words, the `div`'s contents are wider than the `div` itself.

The following HTML and CSS are an example of how to hide part of the `div` if *x* = 250 and *y* = 500:

```
​<div id="outer-div" style="width:250px;overflow:hidden;">
<div style="width:500px;">
....
</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The CSS `overflow:hidden` hides the horizontal scrollbar. If you would like the user to see the horizontal scrollbar, use `overflow:auto`. If the horizontal scrollbar is all you require, then there is no need to write any JavaScript.

---

**The JavaScript**

Changing which part of the `div` is visible based on mouse movement requires JavaScript. One way to accomplish this is to change the scroll position of the `outer-div`. [mootools](/questions/tagged/mootools) has the method [`Element.scrollTo`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3ascrollTo). Other JavaScript frameworks have something similar.

```
$('outer-div').addEvent('mousemove', function(event) {
    $('outer-div').scrollTo(event.client.x);
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbXMC/) for an example.

Comment: This answer looks very much like what I want, except for one thing: I want the oposite! I want the movable smaller div contain the visible part and not hidden part...

Comment: @frodefi I created a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbXMC/2/) based on your updated comments. The concepts are stil the same, except the calculation of the scroll position is different.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `overflow` property:

```
#element {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

You can then scroll the div left or right using the scrollLeft property:

```
document.getElementById("element").scrollLeft = 100;
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vHEPv/

Comment: If you want the element to actually show a scrollbar, you can use `overflow: auto` or `overflow-x: scroll`.